# Swift - Clicked button inside tableview cell does not call the did select row at function of that cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I creating a tableview programatically and each tableview cell have buttons associated to them.

If I click the row I can work out the tag associated with the buttons on that row and then able to edit the title when applying some other functions.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    TmpActionConnectorTag = indexPath.row + 700 //Tag associated to button
}
```

When the button is clicked , I have this code which changes the other button on that row

```
let tag = TmpActionConnectorTag
    let tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton
```

The issue is if I directly click on the button in the tableview cell, the did select row does not get call and no tag value is given. To do it I have to click within the cell first and then the button to be able to know the tag associated with the row.

Is there a way to workout the index row when the button is clicked so I don't have to click the actual cell?

[image]

above is how the cell looks normally and below shows how the cell has to be selected to be able to get the index value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button action won't call the `didSelectRowAt`. You should go for **delegate** method. If not aware about delegate means [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947076/uitableviewcell-buttons-with-action/39947434#39947434)

Answer (score 1):

The cell's button will not trigger `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` instead you need to add a `target` to your button which is typically done within `cellForItemAt`.

**Add target to button within cell**

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = MyTableViewCell()
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCellButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

**Handle button action**

```
@objc func didTapCellButton(sender: UIButton) {
    guard viewModels.indices.contains(sender.tag) else { return } // check element exist in tableview datasource

    //Configure selected button or update model
}
```

Comment: Hi Kye, I am trying your method but the handle button code does not seem to work.  guard viewModels.indices.contains(sender.tag) else { return }

Comment: the guard can be removed if your tableview is not dependent on a data source.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the button's control worked for me.

Programmatically:

editButton.isEnabled = false

~OR~

IB:

Uncheck the Enabled box in the Control section.

[image: Button_Control]

Answer (score -2):

Disabling the button's  User Interaction Control control worked for me.

Programmatically:

editButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.